# error code 1 on pip install MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python, setuptools

I'm trying this on osX:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-istycM/MySQL-python/
```

This is the full message:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 189kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-istycM/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-istycM/MySQL-python/
```

Comment: Did you try installing the MySQL development files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `mysql_config` is in your `PATH` when you run `pip install`, e.g.:

```
locate mysql_config
PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH pip install mysql-python
```